# What is the slowest a character can move while still moving?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, movement

Stacking various slowing effects, such as difficult terrain, being prone (crawling), etc. Assuming a 30 ft movement, and the character will dash if possible, but their movement must be greater than zero in the end result.  Also, for this experiment, it should not be done on a grid, such that movements of less than 5 feet or fractions of a number of feet are still considered movement.

Comment: Are you basically asking about the maximum number of slowing effects that can be stacked on a single creature? Also, should we assume that we are not playing on a grid of 5-foot squares (since in that case any movement less than 5 feet is effectively zero)?

Comment: Are we allowed to assume that their speed or remaining movement can be less than 5? Say we got their speed to 5 and it was then halved, would this become 2.5, 2, or 0?

Comment: Provided the slowing effect stack with each other yes, and not on a grid, otherwise I feel it could be safely assumed the answer would be 5 feet.

Comment: Would something that successfully reduces the target's speed to 5, prevents them from dashing, and then applies every single speed-halving effect at once work as an answer to this question? Or are you looking for some other sort of answer entirely?

Comment: @Medix2 Yes I think that is what i am looking for.

Comment: What's the point of this? Can't they move at any arbitrarily slow speed anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Forced to climb, swim, or crawl

> Each foot of movement costs 1 extra foot (2 extra feet in difficult terrain) when you’re climbing, swimming, or crawling.

Over an area of plant growth

> A creature moving through the area must spend 4 feet of movement for every 1 foot it moves.

But wait.. what if you were a centaur climbing a ladder.

> In addition, any climb that requires hands and feet is especially difficult for you because of your equine legs. When you make such a climb, each foot of movement costs you 4 extra feet, instead of the normal 1 extra foot.

Transmute rock forces 4 feet of movement per foot (+3)

> The ground in the spell’s area becomes muddy enough that creatures can sink into it. Each foot that a creature moves through the mud costs 4 feet of movement,

Wall of sand forces 3 feet of movement per foot (+2) while blinded by it.

> A creature is blinded while in the wall’s space and must spend 3 feet of movement for every 1 foot it moves there.

So a centaur blinded by a wall of sand climbing a rope ladder through mud of transmute rock in an area of plant growth and entangle would need to use 12 feet of movement for every 1 foot it moves.

Hitting the centaur with slow (1/2 speed to 20) and ray of frost (-10 speed) would need to dash in order to have 20 movement speed to move 1 foot.

If he then grabbed a loadstone the speed would be reduced by 5. Then needing two dashes to move 1 foot (from say a cunning action).

Comment: In *Tales from the Yawning Portal* there is ground in the *The Hidden Shrine of Tamoachan* which counts as double difficult terrain, costing 3 foot for every foot to move. But I guess the centaur is already on the ladder and not on the ground.

Comment: I did consider some module specific terrain, however I figured they would be negated or unable to combine with some of the spell effects like transmute rock.